# Azure Isolated Timer Trigger Function not working after deployment to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, .net-5

I am new to Azure and Functions, so please bear with me.

I have a timer trigger isolated .Net 5 function. It does some CRUD operations against SQL database. It works fine locally when tested in Visual Studio 2019. However, when it is deployed into Azure, the trigger isn't invoked. It has Serilog for logging and I see no logging  added to the files.

Using postman, I make a post request to the function. I can see the request count in the graph but nothing more than that.

Where can  I see errors without turning on the application insights?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it is most likely that your logging is not working. Try using the built in log monitoring in the Azure Portal. You can use Log Stream to get a full overview (if your app is not too busy) or you can go to the specific function and there is a "Monitor" option as well.

Comment: Can't use the Monitor as it involves money. Microsoft charges money for everything.

Comment: Well, Microsoft is not a charity

Comment: Could you please check the cron expression by following this MS Q&A link where described that in [free tier Azure Function Time Trigger not firing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/354265/azure-function-time-trigger-not-firing-1.html) and you can use [kudu console to see the logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/resources-kudu?McasTsid=28375). Also refer this [stackify.com/logging-azure-functions](https://stackify.com/logging-azure-functions/) It may help.

Comment: Honestly, this question is very poorly titled; I got here because I'm trying to figure out why my timer function isn't executing, not because I don't know how to get to logs.

Answer (score 3):

> Where can I see errors without turning on the application insights?

Finally i concluded ,that You can use **[Kudu console](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/kudu-console-in-azure/)** to see your logs for your application.
To get kudu console go to **APP service**>**Advanced Tools** >**Go**

[image]

After click on go it will redirect to Kudu homepage like this

[image]

From here you can choose debug console (**cmd**) to download and see your logs

[image]

For more information please refer this MS Q&A discussion  [Azure Function Time Trigger not Firing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/354265/azure-function-time-trigger-not-firing-1.html) .

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just update the project.csproj with following

`<PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>`

`<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>`

After deploying and restart again I see functions are available

Can checkout the following docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1300902/cannot-get-my-net-6-isolated-function-app-on-a-lin

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v4%2Ccmd#functions-class-library-project